# Is there a way to modify an existing SWF file to be local-with-filesystem?

Tags: flash

With Flash gone, I'm currently trying to work to archive an SWF file and trying to preserve it so that it can be played back locally and isn't lost.

Unfortunately, this SWF file relies on an external XML file for some configuration data.

I do have the XML file but when the SWF tries to load it, it results in Error #2148:  Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.

Of course, I don't have the original project for this SWF so I can't just re-export it with changed settings.

It seems like a fix for this would be to somehow patch the SWF file to use local-with-filesystem security, so that it's able to load the XML file and play locally. Is there a way to do that?

Failing that, is there some other workaround that could be used in order to allow this SWF to be played back locally?

Comment: Top of the page 58, the "Use Network" setting: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf

Comment: @Organis Thank you, this led me right to what I needed! Could you repost this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it helped: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a **Use Network** flag on the **File Atributes** tag. Refer the pages 57-58 in [SWF File Format Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf).